# QSerialPort - Is it possible to read() and write() on separate threads?

Tags: multithreading, qt, serial-port

We have a DLL that provides an API for a USB device we make that can appear as a USB CDC com port. We actually use a custom driver on windows for best performance along with async i/o, but we have also used serial port async file i/o in the past with reasonable success as well.

Latency is very important in this API when it is communicating with our device, so we have structured our library so that when applications make API calls to execute commands on the device, those commands turn directly into writes on the API caller's thread so that there is no waiting for a context switch. The library also maintains a listening thread which is always waiting using wait objects on an async read for new responses. These responses get parsed and inserted into thread-safe queues for the API user to read at their convenience.

So basically, we do most of our writing in the API caller's thread, and all of our reading in a listening thread. I have tried porting a version of our code over to using QSerialPort instead of native serial file i/o for Windows and OSX, but I am running into an error whenever I try to write() from the caller's thread (the QSerialPort is created in the listening thread):

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
```

which seems to be due to the creation of another QObject-based WriteOverlappedCompletionNotifier for the notifiers pool used by QSerialPortPrivate::startAsyncWrite().

Is the current 5.2 version of QSerialPort limited to only doing reads and writes on the same thread? This seems very unfortunate as the underlying operating systems do not have any such thread limitations for serial port file i/o. As far as I can tell, the issue mainly has to do with the fact that all of QSerialPort's notifier classes are based on QObject.

Does anyone have a good work around to this? I might try building my own QSerialPort that uses notifiers not based on QObject to see how far that gets me. The only real advantage QObject seems to be giving here is in the destruction of the notifiers when the port closes.

Comment: You should bring some code. Are you sure you created the QSerialPort in the listening thread? How is your threading implementation?

Comment: -1 since the question presupposes presence of a problem without providing any measurements to back it up.

Comment: `Latency is very important` -> and you are using QtSerialPort... Are you serious?! Our library is basically double-click frequency as one of our users put it!

Comment: @FinalContest: We don't use QtSerialPort - we use our own driver in Windows with async i/o. I was evaluating QtSerialPort for other OSes when I ran into these threading issues. We never even got to the point where we could compare performance before we abandoned it.

Answer (score 3):

### Minimal Impact Solution

You're free to inspect the `QSerialPort` and `QIODevice` code and see what would need to change to make the `write` method(s) thread-safe for access from one thread only. The notifiers don't need to be children of the `QSerialPort` at all, they could be added to a list of pointers that's cleaned up upon destruction.

My guess is that perhaps no other changes are necessary to the mainline code, and only mutex protection is needed for access to error state, but you'd need to confirm that. This would have lowest impact on your code.

If you care about release integrity, you should be compiling Qt yourself anyway, and you should be having it as a part of your own source code repository, too. So none of this should be any problem at all.

### On the Performance

"those commands turn directly into writes on the API caller's thread so that there is no waiting for a context switch" Modern machines are multicore and multiple threads can certainly run in parallel without any context switching. The underlying issue is, though: why bother? If you need hard-realtime guarantees, you need a hard-realtime system. Otherwise, nothing in your system should care about such minuscule latency. If you're doing this only to make the GUI feel responsive, there's really no point to such overcomplication.

### A Comms Thread Approach

What I do, with plenty of success, and excellent performance, is to have the communications protocol and the communications port in the same, dedicated thread, and the users in either the GUI thread, or yet other thread(s). The communications port is generally a `QIODevice`, like `QTcpSocket`, `QSerialPort`, `QLocalSocket`, etc. Since the communications protocol object is "just" a `QObject`, it can also live, with the port, in the GUI thread for demostration purposes - it's designed fully asynchronously anyway, and doesn't block for anything but most trivial of computations.

The communications protocol is queuing multiple requests for execution. Even on a single-core machine, once the GUI thread is done submitting all of the requests, the further execution is all in the communications thread.

The `QSerialPort` implementation uses asynchronous OS APIs. There's little to no benefit to further processing those async replies on separate threads. Those operations have very low overhead and you will not gain anything measurable in your latency by trying to do so. Remember: this is not *your* code, but merely code that pushes bytes between buffers. Yes, the context switch overhead may be there on heavily loaded or single-core systems, but unless you can measure the difference between its presence and absence, you're fighting imaginary problems.

It is possible to use *any* `QObject` from multiple threads, of course, as long as you serialize the access to it via the event queue mutex. This is done for you whenever you use the `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` or signal-slot connections.

So, add a trivial wrapper around `QSerialPort` that exposes the `write` as a thread-safe method. Internally, it should use a signal-slot connection. You can call this thread-safe `write` from *any* thread. The overhead in such a call is a mutex lock and `2+n` malloc/free calls, where `n` is the non-zero number of arguments.

In your wrapper, you can also process the `readyRead` signal, and emit a signal with received data. That signal can be processed by a `QObject` living in another thread.

Overall, if you do the measurements correctly, and if your port thread's implementation is correct, you should find no benefit whatsoever to all this complication.

If your communications protocol does heavy data processing, this should be factored out. It could go into a separate `QObject` that can then run on its own thread. Or, it can be simply done using dedicated functors that are executed by `QtConcurrent::run`.

Comment: Tried this solution without success. I started from blockingMaster example. QSerialPort is instanciated in the "run" method of the thread.  I built a Q**D**SerialPort like this `class QDSerialPort : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    QDSerialPort(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE qint64 write(const QByteArray& byteArray){
         serial->write(byteArray);
    }
    
    void setSerial(QSerialPort* serial) {
        this->serial = serial;
    }
  private:
    QSerialPort* serial;

};
`

Comment: I call    `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&s, "write", Qt::DirectConnection, Q_RETURN_ARG(qint64, result), Q_ARG(const QByteArray&, a));
` from the main thread and still have the "Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread".

Comment: A direct connection is exactly like a function call. Qt knows what to do - just remove the `Qt::DirectConnection` argument.

Comment: I did it but still have the "Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread". Is my wrapper correct?

Comment: First of all, you're asking about code that's nowhere to be seen, so this comment doesn't belong here but on a new question. Secondly, the error message you're getting has zilch to do with that method invocation. You didn't properly move *all* of the objects involved in the I/O to the worker thread, so when work is done in the worker, it fails. If you want anything further, ask a question and please include a minimal, compileable example. Look at my [repo](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown) for inspiration.

Comment: You also don't need to have a separate class that does a half-assed job. Make a class with thread-safe `write` method. Then you don't need to write those `invokeMethod` calls. I've fixed the question not to suggest such half-assed measures :) - that one was on me. Bad me.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `QSerialPort` to open and configure the serial port, and `QSocketNotifier` to monitor for read activity (and other `QSocketNotifier` instances for write completion and error handling, if necessary)?

`QSerialPort::handle` should give you the file descriptor you need.  On Windows, if that function returns a Windows `HANDLE`, you can use [_open_osfhandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up, shortly after this discussion I did implement my own thread-safe serial port code for POSIX systems using select() and the like and it is working well on multiple threads in conjunction with Qt and non-Qt applications alike. Basically, I have abandoned using QtSerialPort at all.

Comment: That is a really strange idea. You could have tried out the (e)poll based Qt event loop.

Comment: There were some reasons to take Qt out of this library anyway as I was using it minimally. I replaced the threading, containers, mutexes, etc. with boost, and my binary became significantly smaller.

With regards to your poll() / epoll() comment, my understanding of these is that their real advantage comes when you are waiting on a large number of files. Since we are only dealing with one device here, is there really an advantage over select()?

Comment: As far as I know, libev is significantly faster. There are some benchmarks out there for the Qt event loop. Either way, a move to boost is really nice. For serial port, you could consider asio.